# How to tar 30 Gigas of data on a 50 Giga server?

Tags: linux, tar

I need to send the content of a folder (full of JPEG pics) to a client.

My server has 50 gigas and folder has 30 gigas.
(Zipping JPEG is useless since JPEG is already compressed)

Any idea/strategy on how I can achieve such a thing ?

Regards

Comment: Use a USB stick?

Answer (score 4):

Tar it away via `ssh`:

```
tar zcf - /SRC | ssh user@domain.tld dd of=/remote/server/path/file.tgz
```

Answer (score 1):

tar supports appending to an existing archive, so if you tar up ~10 GB, then delete the originals, you can then do another ~10 GB batch, adding them to the `.tar` with [the `--append` flag](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/appending-files.html). Keep going until everything's in the `.tar` and you've removed all the originals.

Alternatively, attach a new drive, or pay the $10/month for a 1 TB Dropbox account and give them access via that, or put 'em up on something like Amazon S3 for download.

Answer (score 0):

You have some sort of backups right? If not, do that first. Perhaps with rsync and an extra drive, rsync over ssh to another location, or a snapshot if this is a VM on a provider that provides that service on disks.

Once you have good backups, run tar with the `--remove-files` flag. That will delete the source files as they are added to the tar file.

Comment: is it going to remove files while creating the archive or is it going to remove files once the tar is created (in that case, this is quite useless  for me since the tar will take too much space)